# Install (non-bundled) dependencies with a .pyz file?

Tags: python, zipapp

I want to create a python zipapp file that automatically downloads and installs dependencies when run. This is possible by bundling the dependencies in the `.pyz` file itself. However, that explodes the file size from 10kB to 500MB.

I basically want to automatically run `pip install -r requirements.txt` before executing `__main__.py`, but I cannot figure a way to do that.

I've tried putting `requirements.txt` in the archive, but that doesn't do anything. Looking at `zipapp --help` doesn't give any suggestions either.